# Android Dev: How do I extract data from the web and use the data in my app?

Tags: android

I saw this android app called Lyrics App. It provides the lyrics of the song currently played but needs internet connection always. Now, I wanted to make a similar app, that it gets the lyrics from the web for the first time and then saves it to my android device, so that next time a song is played, it'll get the lyrics from the device instead of the web.. no need for constant internet connection.

I've searched already but I can't find the right one for my case. I checked webview, but I think it's just for displaying webcontent, not extracting.

I am new to this, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try...

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.someplace.com");
ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
```

This can be used to grab the whole webpage as a string of html, i.e., `"<html>...</html>"`

**EDIT:** Note, you need to declare the following 'uses-permission' in the android manifest xml file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I tried it with http://www.google.com but I can't seem to make it work.. I get IOException with message www.google.com

Comment: @Jooty: I'm not sure if I can help further unless you post the code you tried. Those four steps I listed above are pretty much what I use for ripping the raw html off any web page.

Comment: I have fixed it already. I didn't know about 'permissions' until now. I added a permission for the application to be able to connect to the network. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Jooty: OK, I'd forgotten I should have mentioned the permissions needed to connect to the Internet. I'll try to remember in future when answering questions on this subject. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

To those that don't already know, each of your android programs has a file called a manifest.

The manifest content is xml, and typically looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

    <uses-permission />
    <permission />
    <permission-tree />
    <permission-group />
    <instrumentation />
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Along with other things, this file is where you specify the uses permissions that your program uses e.g. if it needs to make a phone-call, to upload data etc.

These uses permissions invoke a question-box each upon application installation, giving the user the opportunity to allow or deny your application various services.

Bear (Rawr!) this in mind when programming, because your application will be a better if a user denies your application from uploading and your application still works.

Specific to your application, you need the internet permission. To enable it, add the following uses permission in the manifest file wherever you wish within the  tag at the top and the  tag at the foot:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This will prompt the user to decide, "Do you want to allow this application internet access?"