# Retrieve data from website in android app

Tags: android

How can we retrieve data from a website and parse it into a readable format in the Android application? This means I want to extract data from website and use it in my android application, formatted in my way. It could be any website.

Comment: Ok fine i will ask the website owners... but what actually want is that for example you have a website in which you publish many articles.. i just want to get the headlines of that article in the app.. you can take this as an example..

Comment: Got the xml file... now need to know how to parse the xml into my android app..

Comment: You can look on this one :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android or you can look on this one:
http://blog.andrewpearson.org/2010/07/android-html-parsing.html

Answer (score 17):

You can use `jsoup` to parse any kind of web page. [Here](http://jsoup.org/) you can find the jsoup library and full source code.

Here is an example: http://desicoding.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-parse-html-in-java-jsoup.html

To install in Eclipse:

1. Right Click on project
2. BuildPath
3. Add External Archives
4. select the .jar file

You can parse according to tag/parent/child very comfortably

Comment: how to send data to html page

Comment: Will this jsoup work in android app?? i dunno how it works.. looks nice.. but will this work in my android app??

Comment: The above answer along with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4523525/568169 , works brilliantly!

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.someplace.com");
ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
```

This can be used to grab the whole webpage as a string of html, i.e., "`<html>...</html>"`

**Note** 
You need to declare the following 'uses-permission' in the `android manifest xml file`... answer by @Squonk [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523525/3496570)

And also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the HTML parsing but it is not at all recommended instead ask the website owners to provide web services then you can parse that information.

Comment: I will be uploading the data on my own web server. How do I proceed to include that data in my Android app?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WebView. Simple!!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Webview will load the website and he can get full source as string.But he needs the parsed data to use in his application

Comment: Well, we need to know exactly what he wants to filter out and based on that, we could refine our answers. I like @riser 's answer.

Comment: yes,some web site owners provide data as xml format.That is really great to have.But whatever you are getting in well known format or not you can parse