# Read "XML" content from webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

In my app I have a webview which will give a XML content after a long process of submission. I have to read the XML content of the web page. I tried using JavaScript to do this.

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]+'</head>');");
```

But for some device(browsers) its not calling the JavaScript function. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Help you to fix *what* exactly? Your abuse of `javascript:` URLs? or the complete lack of example of *what* you're trying to do (not *how* you're trying to do it) -- XY problem.

Comment: I have to read an XML page from a webview.

Comment: `I have to read an XML page from a webview.` -- Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761082/retrieve-data-from-website-in-android-app  have you tried this??

Answer (score 0):

Use xml parsing for parse an d view xml content
if you are not familiar with that refer this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I am trying to read XML from web view. After that only we can parse the XML.