# How to I get data from blog into android?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, logic, blogs

I have a blog link (https://truecaller.blog/2018/01/22/life-as-an-android-engineer/)
I need to fetch the text from this blog and show some parts of it on the android screen.
For eg:

1:Find the 10th character and display it on the screen

2:Find every 10th character (i.e. 10th, 20th, 30th, etc.) and display the array on the screen

Comment: and what you have tried so far, what is not working, where is a problem?

Comment: I don't even understand How am I supposed to get this is data and perform actions on it.. @snachmsm

Comment: Found the answer to my question. :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53918665/8528771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution for my question and created a repo for the same using kotlin.
You can find it here: https://github.com/AbD-hashmi/TrueCallerAssignment/tree/development
Basically what is does is gets data from the blog page and makes it usable as a string